# PHPMyadmin: Change Maria DB to MYSQL (Data Base)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I had an issue while working on Backend PHP & MySQL, the PHP my admin is opened with MAria DB and can't log out or change the

```
Server type: MariaDB
```

Also, while trying to edit the config.ini.php, error that I don't have permission, all workaround solutions are for windows OS not for MAC OS

I need some help please to change it as I tried everything and to use the terminal isn't working or anything change the DB to MYSQL even if downloading MYSQL Installer!!

[image]

Comment: Any specific reason for changing?

Comment: I am following an online course and he asked us to use MYSQL instead of MAria and aM just newbie learning and just searched the internet and said Maria DB isn't compatible with MYSQL something like that .. So please advise?

Comment: Hm, MariaDB was developed as a "_[Drop-in Replacement for MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/)_", they should be "99%" compatible. Anyway, do you have a MySQL server running instead of your MariaDB server? PhpMyAdmin is "just" a GUI for MySQL servers. Uninstall MariaDB server, install MySQL server and you should be good to go

Comment: So guys... I can follow along the course with Maria DB .. Actually I had installed Xampp on my mac and It should initiate the MYSQL and all of the stuff ... For PHP my admin never allows me to logout or changes anything "Don't have permission to play around in php.ini.config file"